# Datatable selections I did on the first page get "forgotten"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I select some checkboxes in one page on the paginated table, then move to another page to select more, then the selections I did on the first page get "forgotten". In other words it doesn't seem possible to select multiple checkboxes simultaneously on different pages of a paginated datatable.

Is there any way round this?

Comment: You need to use some server side processing in order to keep checkboxes state client side, something like this: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/3315#Comment_3315  You could just use some persistent data client side or even just a variable but it really depends your expected behaviour

Comment: where is your code..??

Comment: @A.Wolff Server side processing is necessarily ? Is there any way without server-side

Comment: @MelikşahSaidKUTLU You could just keep track of previously checked checkboxes in a array. I'd for each table page set an array of array keeping the index of checked ones relative to each page. But if you want more specific help, you have to provide a concrete sample